# Method to determine 'true' address location in R

Tags: r, geocoding, prediction

I have a large dataset of AddressIds which needs to be cleaned. End users can enter the coordinates belonging to an AddressId themselves, and as a result some AddressIds have many (> 20) longitudes and latitudes that slightly differ (sometimes just a few metres).  So for example:

```
AddressID      Longitude        Latitude
1234           77.037692        38.89864
1234           77.037872        38.88775
1234           77.048522        38.78553
```

Now, I would like to determine which longitude and which latitude is the most accurate with help from R. Taking the median or something like that is not possible, as the coordinates slightly differ and almost never exactly the same coordinates were entered.

My idea is that the longitude (respectively latitude) with the shortest distance to an other longitude (respectively latitude) should be the most accurate one. Now I am wondering which package and method I could use best for answering a question like this.

Comment: Something relevant for you! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/computing-an-averaged-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: How should the most accurate record be if you have only two records for an AddressId? average two records or just randomly choose one?

Comment: Take a look at the ggmap package.  The function geocode will return the lat and long of an address according to Google.   Of course whether this is the "true" one is still up for debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go using the method I linked in the comments, only base functions required:

```
# Read in data.
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "AddressID      Longitude        Latitude
1234           77.037692        38.89864
                 1234           77.037872        38.88775
                 1234           77.048522        38.78553")


# Get the radians.
df$LongitudeRadians <- df$Longitude * pi / 180
df$LatitudeRadians <- df$Latitude * pi / 180

# Get the cartesian coordinates.
df$x <- sin(df$LatitudeRadians) * cos(df$LongitudeRadians)
df$y <- sin(df$LatitudeRadians) * sin(df$LongitudeRadians)
df$z <- cos(df$LatitudeRadians)

# Get the means.
avgs <- aggregate.data.frame(df[c(1,6:8)], by = list(df$AddressID), FUN = "mean")

# Convert back to degrees.
avgs$LongitudeRadians <- atan2(avgs$y, avgs$x)
avgs$LatitudeRadians <- atan2(sqrt(avgs$x^2 + avgs$y^2), avgs$z)

avgs$Longitude <- avgs$LongitudeRadians * 180 / pi
avgs$Latitude <- avgs$LatitudeRadians * 180 / pi

avgs <- avgs[c(2,8:9)]
```

The result is *fractionally* different to just doing the means of the longitude and latitude, probably because your given long/lat are so close together.

But hey, I learned something about spherical coordinate systems today, so if even if this gets downvoted to hell I enjoyed myself.